# Get results from two models in Haystack/whoosh

Tags: django, django-haystack

I used Haystack with on model and it worked just fine. But when I tried to use two models, it keeps returning None.

**These are my models:**

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**These are the classes in search_indexes.py:**

```
class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    body = indexes.CharField(model_attr='body')
    pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')

    def get_model(self):
        return Note

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())


class PeopleIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    full_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    desc = indexes.CharField(model_attr='description')

    def get_model(self):
        return People

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

**This is the view:**

```
def root(request):
    form = NoteSearchForm(request.GET)
    form2 = PeopleSearchForm(request.GET)
    results = form.search()
    results2 = form2.search()
    return render(request, 'search/search.html', {
        'notes': results,
        'people': results2
    })
```

**Here are the forms:**

```
class NoteSearchForm(SearchForm):

    def no_query_found(self):
        return self.searchqueryset.all()

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(NoteSearchForm, self).search()

        if not self.is_valid():
            return self.no_query_found()

        # sqs = sqs.order_by('title')

        return sqs


class PeopleSearchForm(SearchForm):

    def no_query_found(self):
        return self.searchqueryset.all()

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(PeopleSearchForm, self).search().models(Note, People)

        if not self.is_valid():
            return self.no_query_found()

        return sqs
```

If other files help, I will provide them too.

How do I search from two models?

P.S. It is working for Note, but not for People

Comment: Can you show also forms classes?

Comment: are there valid templates (search templates) for this two models?

Comment: also is it possible to check if people data is in index? (for elastic search with direct query etc) ?

Comment: @MichaelPlakhov, it is working now after I added sqs = super(PeopleSearchForm, self).search().models(Note, People). Thanx)