# Search from two models with Haystack

Tags: django, django-haystack

How to have Haystack search from two models?

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Implementing two indexes did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have registered search index for all models you can specify which of it to search e.g.:

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(content='foo').models(People, Note)
```

if not specified it will search everywhere

Indexes should be like

```
class PeopleIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    ....

class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    ....
```

in appropriate search_indexes.py in apps

P.S. make sure all models is indexed by doing direct queries to search engine you using (if possible)

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668796/get-results-from-two-models-in-haystack-whoosh . I would be really grateful. Here I posted more of my code.